# How to include Bootstrap in container specific scss?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm working to upgrade to the latest version of [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) & Bootstrap, I used to have: reactstrap in my package.json and bootstrap SCSS downloaded in my client/src/styles/bootstrap directory.

I now have in my package.json:

```
"reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
```

For my container & component specific SCSS files, this used to work:

**home.jsx:**

```
import '../styles/home/Home.css'
```

**home.scss**

```
@import "../bootstrap/variables";
@import "../bootstrap/custom";
@import "../bootstrap/mixins/breakpoints";

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    ...
}
```

These @import files are no longer available with the new reactstrap and Bootstrap. How can import bootstrap items like `@import "../bootstrap/mixins/breakpoints";`? Or am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import files from the bootstrap module in the node_modules directory. So the path from your root directory would be `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints`.